# Express the negation of the statement limit

Tags: discrete-mathematics, continuity

**Express the negation of the statement**:

$ \forall \epsilon >0 , \exists \delta>0 , \forall x , 0 <|x-a| <\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-a| <\epsilon \ $

**Answer:**

The negation is-

$ \exists \epsilon >0 , \forall \delta>0 , \exists x , 0 <|x-a| <\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-a| > \epsilon \ $

**Am I right?**

Comment: You haven't negated the inmost part of the statement: the $\implies$.

Comment: You neen to add parenthesis in both statements.